# Can a SharePoint Calendar Send out Meeting Invites to Participates in Outlook

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, outlook

I am not sure why my question was deleted but I will ask again.

I have a calendar in SharePoint 2013 that I need to be able to send invites to participants in Outlook.

Is there a way, either out the box using a workflow or programmatically that would allow this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to send out meeting invites from SharePoint to outlook, here is an third-party Calendar E-Mail Extension that could achieve this, please refer to:

https://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/invite-attendees-from-sharepoint-calendar/

https://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/calendar-events-invites-add-in-now-available-for-sharepoint-online/